# Windows crashes when I try to reload site running on XAMPP

Tags: windows, crash, xampp, markdown, statamic

I am developing a statamic (flat file CMS) site and when I am reloading the site running on a XAMPP machine, my windows crashes. It showes up the same error every time:

```
Stop code: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
What failed: cldflt.sys
```

The crashes are since I edited this file: site/content/pages/index.md. I've already tried to run this site with WAMP and MAMP but windows crashes the same way every time I try to reload the page. I also can't find anything useful in the Windows Event Viewer and I couldn't find any fixes to this either. Even when I reset the index.md to its default, the crash comes up anyways!

Did anyone got the same issue or knows a fix for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, I've got an solution for this one.

This error is caused by the cldflt.sys which is responsible for some processes in OneDrive. **So I moved my project directory to an non-synced folder and everything is fine.** Otherwise, you could end the OneDrive task but I think this isn't the shiny solution. Yes, I tried these workarounds with those deactivate-this-file methods but then the site isn't loading evermore... whyever.

Hope I could help you.